# How to configure breakpoints and picture to use span data-picture

Tags: 7, media

I have follow the documentation that appear here: [Picture documentation](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/picture), but I'm not able to configure the module to use the same html that appear in the examples.

This is the code from the example [Page](http://picture7w.h011.attiks.com/node/1):

```
<span data-picture> 
  <span data-src="http://picture7w.h011.attiks.com/sites/picture7w.h011.attiks.com/files/styles/piccustom_user_tablet_1_5x/public/field/image/38054784.jpg?itok=zyO3uMRu" data-width="1300" data-height="867"></span>
  <noscript>&lt;img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://picture7w.h011.attiks.com/sites/picture7w.h011.attiks.com/files/styles/piccustom_user_tablet_1_5x/public/field/image/38054784.jpg?itok=zyO3uMRu" width="1300" height="867" alt="" /&gt;</noscript>
  <img alt="picture" width="1024" height="683" class="match" src="http://picture7w.h011.attiks.com/sites/picture7w.h011.attiks.com/files/styles/piccustom_user_desk_1x/public/field/image/38054784.jpg?itok=3Or90dqg">
</span>
```

Instead I get this html code:

```
<picture title="ejemplo">
  <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
  <source srcset="http://domain.new/sites/default/files/styles/verisure_breakpoints_theme_tc_mobile_1x/public/block/footer/LADRONA_en.jpg?itok=TrydhOr5 990w" media="only screen and (max-width: 767px)" sizes="(max-width: 767px)">
  <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
  <img alt="ejemlo" title="ejemplo" src="http://domain.new/sites/default/files/styles/verisure_breakpoints_theme_tc_retina_1x/public/block/footer/LADRONA_en.jpg?itok=DPGm0iG4">
</picture>
```

Any idea how to configure the module?

Thanks

Oskar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo page you've linked says it was `Submitted by admin on Thu, 04/25/2013 - 13:31`. That's over 1 year ago.

What makes you think the output you're seeing isn't correct for your current installed version of Picture? If your breakpoints are installed and configured correctly as in the [documentation](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/picture) you have linked, then the images should be responsive.